# How to use RequireJS to load a server module that requires authentication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, qliksense

I need to load a script which is located at a server, and it requires authentication. I know both user and pass, but I don't know how to pass them to RequireJS.

The code looks like this:

> ```
> require.config({
>     baseUrl: //directory where the script file is located
> });
>
> require(["js/qlik"], function(qlik) {
>   // code
> });
> ```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? Usually you should check user credentials & rights on the http layer. What is your specific use case?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to access the Qlik Sense API, like it's showed here:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/November2018/Subsystems/APIs/Content/Sense_ClientAPIs/CapabilityAPIs/qlik-interface-interface.htm
I think that the problem is that this guide is tought for a public access file, but mine is not.
I tried also to download the file and save it manually as a module, but the problem is that Node can't find it, as it wasn't properly installed.